# How to get navbar elements to show up inline in bootstrap 3?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

For some reason in bootstrap, I am having 2 problems:

1) The content of my "Home, INdex, Bold..." does not show up whatsoever.
2) I want the content of the "Home, Index, Bold" to show up in the same line as "Logo Here".

My code and css:

```
<nav class="dt qf py tu eu app-navbar">
  <div class="e">
    <div class="pv">

      <a class="l" href="../">
        <span>Logo Here</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pw collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pk">
        <li>
          <a href="..//index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="../minimal/index.html">Index</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="../bold/index.html">Bold</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="../docs/index.html">Docs</a>
        <li>
          <a href="../docs/index.html">Mre Docs</a>
        </li></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 979px) {

  #midCol.affix-top {
      position:fixed;
      width:265px;
      margin-right:10px;

  }

  #midCol.affix {
      position:static;
      width:100%;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .affix,.affix-top {
      position:fixed;
  }
}


    @media (min-width: 768px)
.pw {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

    @media (min-width: 768px)
.pk {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.e {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.pz {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}    

    .l {
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    height: 50px;
}

    .app-navbar {
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: .15em;
            padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: transparent;
}


*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    @media (min-width: 768px)
.pz {
    display: none;
}

    element.style {
}
.qf .pz {
    border-color: transparent;
}
.p-x-0 {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
button {
    overflow: visible;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.app-navbar {
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: .15em;
}
.eu {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

    .navbar-nav {
        margin:0;
            float: right !important;
    margin-right: -10px;
    }

    li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
            list-style: none;
}

    .pw {
        width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    }    
@media (min-width: 768px)
.pw.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

Comment: To start, some of your **media queries** are written without any opening and closing brackets: compare your first media query with your last to see the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the snippet. It's a copy of your HTML and CSS. i only added the following to it:

```
li{
   display:inline-block;
}
```

you can change `li` to your specific selector.

```css
@media (min-width: 979px) {

  #midCol.affix-top {
      position:fixed;
      width:265px;
      margin-right:10px;

  }

  #midCol.affix {
      position:static;
      width:100%;
  }

}

@media (min-width: 767px) {
  .affix,.affix-top {
      position:fixed;
  }
}


    @media (min-width: 768px)
.pw {
    width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}

    @media (min-width: 768px)
.pk {
    float: right !important;
    margin-right: -10px;
}

.e {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}

.pz {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding: 9px 10px;
    margin-top: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
}    

    .l {
    float: left;
    padding: 14px 10px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 22px;
    height: 50px;
}

    .app-navbar {
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: .15em;
            padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
            background-color: #ffffff;
    border-color: transparent;
}


*:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

    @media (min-width: 768px)
.pz {
    display: none;
}

    element.style {
}
.qf .pz {
    border-color: transparent;
}
.p-x-0 {
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    padding-right: 0 !important;
}
button, select {
    text-transform: none;
}
button {
    overflow: visible;
}
button, input, optgroup, select, textarea {
    color: inherit;
    font: inherit;
    margin: 0;
}
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.app-navbar {
    font-size: 13px;
    letter-spacing: .15em;
}
.eu {
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

    .navbar-nav {
        margin:0;
            float: right !important;
    margin-right: -10px;
    }

    li {
    display: list-item;
    text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
            list-style: none;
}
li{
display:inline-block;
}
    .pw {
        width: auto;
    border-top: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    }    
@media (min-width: 768px)
.pw.collapse {
    display: block !important;
    height: auto !important;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    overflow: visible !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="dt qf py tu eu app-navbar">
  <div class="e">
    <div class="pv">

      <a class="l" href="../">
        <span>Logo Here</span>
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="pw collapse" id="navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pk">
        <li>
          <a href="..//index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="active">
          <a href="../minimal/index.html">Index</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="../bold/index.html">Bold</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="../docs/index.html">Docs</a>
        <li>
          <a href="../docs/index.html">Mre Docs</a>
        </li></li>
      </ul>
    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also an opportunity if your links are not show up, you can use **collapse in** class instead of collapse at div with id id="navbar-collapse"